# passing schema name in mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've created a procedure in mysql which takes schema name as a parameter and want to retreive value from a table in that schema.
my procedure is

```
    CREATE procedure `get_client_id` (IN p_schema VARCHAR(12), OUT l_client_id VARCHAR(5))
    deterministic

    BEGIN
     declare l_client_id varchar(5);
    SET @sql_text = concat('SELECT lookup_value INTO l_client_id FROM ',p_schema,'.lookup_code_detail where lookup_code = ''CLIENT_ID''' );
      PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    END
```

when I call the procedure

```
    call get_client_id('SMS',@l_client_id);
```

its throwing this error

```
     00:11:15   call get_client_id('SMS',@l_client_id)  Error Code: 1327. Undeclared variable: l_client_id  0.000 sec
```

I've tried creating procedure as

```
CREATE procedure `get_client_id` (IN p_schema VARCHAR(12), OUT l_client_id VARCHAR(5))
deterministic

BEGIN
 declare l_client_id varchar(5);
 declare param_db varchar(5);
 set param_db = p_schema;
SELECT concat('schema is ', param_db);
SELECT lookup_value 
INTO l_client_id 
FROM param_db.lookup_code_detail 
where lookup_code = 'CLIENT_ID';

END
```

but this also throws error

```
  00:25:44  call get_client_id('SMS',@l_client_id)  Error Code: 1146 Table 'param_db.lookup_code_detail' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> SET @sql_text = concat('SELECT lookup_value INTO l_client_id FROM...
> ```
>
> Error Code: 1327. Undeclared variable: l_client_id

You can't reference procedure-local variables in a dynamic SQL statement. This is because the dynamic SQL execution doesn't have any access to local variables in your stored procedure. It's like it's executing the dynamic SQL statement in a different scope.

As a workaround, you can store the results of the dynamic SQL statement in session variables instead of local variables. Session variables have the `@` prefix.

```
SET @sql_text = concat('SELECT lookup_value INTO @l_client_id FROM...
```

> ```
> FROM param_db.lookup_code_detail
> ```
>
> Error Code: 1146 Table 'param_db.lookup_code_detail' doesn't exist

You cannot use the `param_db` variable in the way you're doing. Variables can take the place of scalar values only, not identifiers.